# Sitecore Remove "Publishable To" Check Box

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore, when selecting an item and going under the Publish > Restrictions (Change) tab there is a "Publishable To" drop down signifying that a particular item is publishable up to the specified date(end date). I need to have that drop down removed so that users do not select an end date.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Publish dialog control here:

**\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\Set Publishing\Set Publishing.xml**

To hide the date range - just replace

```
<Border ID="PublishPanel">
```

with

```
<Border ID="PublishPanel" style="display: none">
```

Comment: Great! I'll give this a try in a moment.

Comment: I found the Set Publishing XML file and that is definitely a great starting point. However, I just need to remove the "Publishable To" drop down for one item.
What file reads this XML? Maybe I can add conditional code to not display the drop down for that one item.

Comment: I'd try wrap "Publishable To" with <Border ID="AnotherPanel" style="display: none">.
The code beside is: Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Dialogs.SetPublishing.SetPublishingForm,Sitecore.Client

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Sitecore UI and write your custom code

1. Copy the Sitecore UI Set Publishing.xml and place it in the folder Override with the same directory structure: 
   Website\sitecore\shell\Override\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\Set Publishing
2. Then you can modified the xml in the override folder and change the codebeside.